# How to use residual analysis to remove the effect of confounding variables in a model in R

Tags: r, multiple-regression, stepwise-regression, residuals

I want to find which soil variables better explain plant productivity, using a database that contains information for about 100 forests plots across Europe.
These plots have only one species per plot, but overall there are 4 different species in the dataset. These plots also have different climate conditions (temperature, precipitation,...). My final goal is finding out which combination of the more than 20 different soil variables better explain plant productivity. However, both climate and species may confound the analysis because both affect plant growth (some species grow more than others, and plants grown in warmer climates may grow more). I am only interested in plant growth due to soil characteristics, so I need to get rid of the species and climate effects on plant productivity that may confound the analysis. According to what I have read I could just include all variables in the model: soil, climate and species (factor of 4 levels), like this:

```
fit <- lm(scale(IVMean)~scale(SILT)+scale(SAND)+scale(PHCACL2)+scale(OC)+
                        scale(EXCHCA)+scale(EXCHK)+scale(EXCHMG)+scale(EXCHMN)+
                        scale(EXCHNA)+scale(EXCHAL)+scale(EXCHFE)+scale(N_NO3)+
                        scale(S_SO4)+scale(N_NH4)+scale(BS)+scale(CN)+scale(Temp)+
                        scale(Precip)+scale(Rad)+scale(PET)+species)
```

IVMean = mean stem volume increment (productivity). Note climate variables (temperature, precipitation, radiation and potential evapotranspiration -PET-) and species at the end, and the standardisation of all variables with `scale()`.

After this, I could run a stepwise regression analysis to preliminarily find which variables are the most important explaining plant productivity.

```
library(MASS)
step <- stepAIC(fit, direction="backward")
step$anova # display results
```

Which renders the following best minimal model:

```
Final Model:
scale(IVMean) ~ scale(PHCACL2) + scale(EXCHCA) + scale(EXCHMG) + 
    scale(EXCHMN) + scale(BS) + scale(Temp) + scale(PET) + species

> model <- lm(scale(IVMean) ~ scale(PHCACL2) + scale(EXCHCA) + scale(EXCHMG) + 
+               scale(EXCHMN) + scale(BS) + scale(Temp) + scale(PET) + species, 
+             data = icp)
> summary(model)

Call:
lm(formula = scale(IVMean) ~ scale(PHCACL2) + scale(EXCHCA) + 
    scale(EXCHMG) + scale(EXCHMN) + scale(BS) + scale(Temp) + 
    scale(PET) + species, data = icp)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1.13836 -0.41522 -0.02816  0.35094  1.65587 

Coefficients:
                   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)        -0.37587    0.16967  -2.215 0.030897 *  
scale(PHCACL2)      0.58776    0.20617   2.851 0.006128 ** 
scale(EXCHCA)      -0.38061    0.19025  -2.001 0.050381 .  
scale(EXCHMG)      -0.37374    0.14686  -2.545 0.013769 *  
scale(EXCHMN)       0.13102    0.09970   1.314 0.194241    
scale(BS)           0.39502    0.19428   2.033 0.046871 *  
scale(Temp)         1.34654    0.32033   4.204 9.74e-05 ***
scale(PET)         -0.62177    0.29749  -2.090 0.041250 *  
speciesoak         -1.24553    0.34788  -3.580 0.000726 ***
speciespicea_abies  1.38679    0.25031   5.540 8.79e-07 ***
speciesscots_pine   0.02627    0.25960   0.101 0.919769    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.6411 on 55 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.6522,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.5889 
F-statistic: 10.31 on 10 and 55 DF,  p-value: 1.602e-09
```

The final model includes 5 soil variables, 2 out of 4 climate variables, and species. So far so good?

However, this seems to be not good enough for my supervisor. Rather, he asked me to do an analysis of the residuals to “get rid of climate and species effects”! To be honest, I have no idea what he is talking about, and I was afraid to ask because he sounded like something I should know since my childhood. Perhaps he meant I should study which SOIL variables can explain the residuals of productivity ~ climate * species? Please, help me find out which type of analysis of the residuals would make sense to focus on soil effects eliminating climate and species effects.

This is the only thing I can think of:

```
# Study the importance of confounding effects:
confounding     <- IVMean ~ (Temp + Precip + PET + Rad) * species 
confounding.res <- residuals(confounding)
lm(confounding.res ~scale(SILT)+scale(SAND)+scale(PHCACL2)+scale(OC)+scale(EXCHCA)+
                    scale(EXCHK)+scale(EXCHMG)+scale(EXCHMN)+scale(EXCHNA)+
                    scale(EXCHAL)+scale(EXCHFE)+scale(N_NO3)+scale(S_SO4)+
                    scale(N_NH4)+scale(BS)+scale(CN))
```

This way maybe I could study which soil variables explain what climate and species effects could not explain? I don’t know if it makes any sense. I am open to suggestions and alternatives.

Comment: You don't need to ask a new question. Please do not delete & re-ask the same Q. If it doesn't get enough attention, the new 1 won't either. You can edit it to 'bump' it, but don't spam the main page. Bear in mind that some Qs take a while to get answered. You are asking strangers to do you a favor; it may take a while.

Comment: I am sorry about that, the system suggested that since my question was marked as duplicated, after reformulating the Q I could simply post a new Q, and that is what I did because I don’t have much experience and because I didn’t know that it would bump  after editing the post. Sorry